Getting error when doing su in a newly setup chroot user in arch-linux
I created a jail user in arch linux which can able to perform below all use cases.

su(switch user) from any user in the system should redirect to its home directory within chroot jail
with ssh also it should land defined path.
the user should not have root privileges.
bashrc file also have been sourcing.

For the reference i am sharing below config i configured
jail/
│
├── bin
│
├── dev
│
├── etc
│   ├── passwd
│   ├── group
│   ├── shadow
│   └── environment
│
├── home
│   └── jaileduser
│       ├── .bashrc
│       ├── .profile
│       └── .bash_history
│
├── lib
│   ├── ld-<version>.so
│   ├── libc-<version>.so
│   ├── libdl-<version>.so
│  
│
├── lib64
│   ├── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
│   ├── libm.so.6
│  
│
├── usr
│   ├── bin
│   ├── lib
│ 
│
└── var
    ├── log

etc files in chroot as below
/jail/etc/
├── group               
├── login.defs          
├── nsswitch.conf       
├── pam.d/              
│   ├── su             
│   ├── system-auth     
│   ├── system-local-login 
│   └── system-login    
├── passwd              
└── shadow              

password file entry
jailed-user:x:1003:1003::/jail/home/jailed-user:/bin/jail-shell

jail-shell script as below
#!/bin/bash
sudo chroot /jail /bin/su jailed-user

sudo file entry already did with specific entry
Issue i am getting
su: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does the user have a corresponding /etc/shadow entry?

the user having the same entries in /etc/shadow and inside the jailed dir, copied only jailed user.
